# Add H1 & div element in jQuery syntax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, syntax

I try to edit a line of jquery code to add two div elements in addition to this code! (see below)

Currently only the element "name" is displayed, but i wish i could style it via my css and add more tags elements!

Could you help me with this because i'm newbie in jQuery/javascript?

```
$("#tip").show().html(wmConfig["points"][e]["name"]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the jQuery documentation, you see the html function take HTML string.
http://api.jquery.com/html/

I'm not sure what do you want to do.
If you want append the divs after the name, the 2 previous answer work.

If you want put the name in 2 div, you can simply write the 2 div around in the html function.

```
$("#tip").show().html('<div><div>'+wmConfig["points"][e]["name"]+'</div></div>');
```

You can also add classes and ids.

Answer (score 0):

The `append` method will allow you to add elements to another element.

```
$("#tip").append("<div>Div1</div><div>Div2</div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this;

```
$current_tip = $("#tip").show().html(wmConfig["points"][e]["name"]);

$current_tip.append('<div></div>'); //add first div
$current_tip.append('<div></div>'); //add second div
$current_tip.css('border' , '1px solid black'); //sample: add a css style in your #tip
```